# Highlight point on image map

Tags: asp.net, imagemap

I am working on imagemap, there are points on my image, I want to mark one of point upon clicking of a button, also please give me idea how can I can control the coordinates because my image is resizeable/dynamic, every time image size will be changed.

[http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1330/imgmaps.png http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1330/imgmaps.png](http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1330/imgmaps.png)

Many Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems interesting, but easily possible,
Take and imagebutton control and load your image into it, in the server side click event of it, you will get co-ordintates of the clicked point, you can simply use GDI+ library of .net framework to draw a point on your image.

I hope this helps